# Could "const for all" mean the constants are different?

Tags: notation, quantifiers

I read this in a paper:

$$ \lambda_m = \mbox{const} \quad \mbox{for all} \quad  m \in \left\{1,2,\cdots,M\right\} $$

Does this mean that all $\lambda_m$ are the same, or that they're all constant functions, but with different constants?

The context: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/inyO7.png]

Comment: Without context, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: It's from [Some Improvements in the Measurement of Variable Latency Acoustically Evoked Potentials in Human EEG](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6862512). I'll supply some more context.

Comment: I'm not allowed to post images, so could someone edit this into the question? http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIoIe.png

Comment: Usually this notation means that each $\lambda_m$ is constant, but the constants can be different. Otherwise the constant should be given a name, e.g. $\lambda_m = C$ where $C$ is constant, or they could just write $\lambda_1 = \cdots = \lambda_m = \text{const}$.

Comment: @Johan The image was really big and seemed to take over the question area in a confusing way, so instead of inlining it I just added a link.

Comment: @Mark: even so it is worth saving a click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with [Yuval Filmus's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151612/could-const-for-all-mean-the-constants-are-different#comment349215_151612) both in the abstract and in the specific. That is, generally we would write something like
$$ \lambda_n = \lambda_m \qquad \forall n,m\in\mathbb{N} $$
or 
$$ \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \cdots = \lambda_n = \cdots $$
or
$$ \lambda_n = C \qquad \forall n \in\mathbb{N}$$
if we want it to mean that all of the $\lambda_n$ are equal.

This is also the case, I believe, in the context. Note that the author refers to functions $e_m(k) = e(k - \lambda_m)$ and states that

> i.e., all $e_m(k)$ have identical shape and can differ only by a time-shift (latency) $\lambda_m$.

If all $\lambda_m$ were to be the same constant, there's hardly any point in defining $e_m$'s as different functions! Hence it is more natural to interpret the statement as requiring that $\lambda_m$ being independent of $k$, with the possibility that $\lambda_n\neq \lambda_m$.

Comment: Congratulations on hitting 20k. Finally you can be trusted.